# Sharepoint - Permissions

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

In the root page, I have web parts - Announcements and Events, and hyperlinks to different Document Libraries and lets say Group X and Y has permissions for this. There is also an image which directs to another page (ex. Manager Sales), which has different document libraries.
I am able to set up different permissions for all document libraries, but I would like the Group X to not have access to the image link.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript api to check user groups, you could find the script [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/979b2bda-30d4-482f-ae56-fce5f98573c8/forum-faq-hide-sharepoint-list-ribbon-command-based-on-user-groups?forum=sharepointdevelopment), then you could hide the image link for Group X users by jQuery or CSS.[hide element by jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_hide.asp)

```
 function CheckUserGroups() {
            var groups = ["Visitors", "Designers"]
            IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroups(groups, function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
                if (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
                    //your hide logic
                }
            });

        }
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CheckUserGroups, 'SP.js');
```